# OCR Image recognition plugin for firefox and chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser-addons, ocr

Sometimes i need to OCR images that I stumble upon on some webpages. I would like to know if there are any **plugins** for Firefox and Chrome that would allow me to upload desired image for processing on their servers, recognize it and send me back the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you upload a pdf file to Google Drive, it will automatically make it text searchable, and also give you the options in the upload box to convert it to a google word (editable) file.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question? He's looking for plugins for Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: ***And*** he says “images,” which typically refers to JPEGs, GIFs, PNGs, etc.